# Constant sequence of partial sums in a diverging series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

In the harmonic series, we have $$|H_{2n}−H_n|\geq \frac{1}{2}$$ for all $n$, which implies divergence. However, the partial sums from $n$ to $2n$, evaluated at $n$, equal $\ln(2)$ for all $n$. Doesn't this imply the sequence of partial sums has converged to the value $\ln(2)$, which in turn, implies the series should converge? I feel like I'm not understanding something fundamental about the Cauchy criterion and convergence etc -- is this not a sequence of partial sums at all, due to the funny things we're doing with the interval? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to be careful as to which partial sums you're talking about. Convergence of a series means that the partial sums from $0$ to $n$ converge as $n\to\infty$. You've shown that the partial sums from $n$ to $2n$ converge, and that's entirely different.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So what I have shown is, in effect, that *a* sequence of partial sums converges, not *the* sequence? Could we refer to this as a convergent subseries then?

Comment: Not is "subseries" is intended to mean what I think it does. Even for a subseries, the relevant partial sums would all have to begin at the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a minor thing: the partial sums from $n$ to $2n$ approach $\ln{2}$, but will never actually equal it. (Why?)

Second, more major thing: In fact, what you have shown is that the sequence of partial sums $\{ H_n\}$ is not Cauchy, and thus not convergent. Indeed, if it were Cauchy, then by definition $|H_{2n} - H_n| \to 0$. This is because for any $\epsilon > 0$, there would have to exist $N(\epsilon)$ for which $|H_m - H_n| < \epsilon$ whenever $m, n > N(\epsilon)$; we then choose $m = 2n$ here.

Comment: For the first question, my guess is that's the definition of a limiting value -- it approaches but doesn't equal. Is this too hand - wavy?

Thank you for the other feedback -- between Andrea's comment and yours it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @rage_man: there is no requirement that the function never equals its limiting value. For example, constant functions for example equal their limiting value everywhere! Another less boring example: $\sin{x}/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and it attains this value at all multiples of $\pi$. The reason there is never equality is that all partial sums, and thus their differences, are rational, while $\ln{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Ha, wrong on two accounts then -- I wouldn't have thought of any of that. Thanks again!